# git push heroku master - dezalgo - npm ERR! code ENOENT

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

Running
`git push heroku master`
gives the following error message:

```
remote: Installing any new modules (package.json)  
remote: npm ERR! path  
 /tmp/build_946cfa00bc649e92ea9db4ad388e3eab/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo
remote: npm ERR! code ENOENT .  
remote: npm ERR! errno -2 .  
remote: npm ERR! syscall rename .  
remote: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/tmp/build_946cfa00bc649e92ea9db4ad388e3eab/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo' -> '/tmp/build_946cfa00bc649e92ea9db4ad388e3eab/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.dezalgo.DELETE' .  
remote: npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.    
remote: npm ERR! enoent .   
remote:       
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR! /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-20T11_17_57_014Z-debug.log
remote:  
remote: -----> Build failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that in your project, to ignore node_modules first, if you didn't do that, you can run these from your terminal of the project.

```
echo 'node_modules' >> .gitignore
git rm -r --cached node_modules
git commit -m "ignore node_modules"
```

Then try deploying on heroku again.

Comment: The solution worked the first time i tried it. The error came back the next day and then the solution failed me. I solved the problem a week later by deleting all npm folders, reinstalling and then updating all packages. Maybe the update did it.